# display error message on form if the message is not empty angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a register form and I wish to display an error message on the form, in case something went wrong.

In my .ts file, I have the following code :-

```
onSubmit(email, password, name, surname, username, homephonenumber, mobilenumber){
this._userService.register(email, password, name, surname, username, homephonenumber, mobilenumber)
  .subscribe((result) => {
    if (result.success == "True") {
      //this._userService.login(email, password);
    }
    else
    {
      this.errorMessage = result.message;
    }
});
```

}

And in my form I have the following:-

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-if="{{errorMessage}}"></div>
```

This is throwing an error in the console:-

```
Can't bind to 'ng-if' since it isn't a known property of 'div'
```

How can I get the error message to display?

Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-if` is angularjs syntax.
For angular 2 change it to :

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="errorMessage"></div>
```

Angular 2 template docs : [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html)